# Do I get the fees defined on the incoming or outgoing channel when routing a payment?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-routing, lightning-fees

Say my node (Y) routes a 1000sat payment from A to B and I set the fees on the A-Y channel to 1000ppm and on the Y-B channel to 2000pm. (Zero base fee). How much fees has A to pay me? 1sat or 2sat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2sat.

The fee is always charged on the outgoing channel